# Question: Finding inverse when an integral is given

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am stuck in the following question:

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\sin x}1+\sin(\sin(t))dt$

Find $(f^{-1})'(0)$

I've tried FTOC part I, and then using the formula of derivative of inverse functions find $(f^{-1})(0)$, but I am unable to solve it. How should I go about this? Any hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the rule for derivative of inverse functions. If $g$ is inverse of $f$ then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1/f'(0)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
f\left( f^{-1}( x)\right) =x\\
f'\left( f^{-1}( x)\right) *\left( f^{-1}( x)\right) '=1\\
( from\ Chain\ Rule)\\
\left( f^{-1}( x)\right) '=\frac{1}{f'\left( f^{-1}( x)\right)}\\
( f^{-1}( 0) '=\frac{1}{f'\left( f^{-1}( 0)\right)}\\
Now,\ from\ the\ original\ eqn,\\
f( x) =\int ^{sinx}_{0}( 1+sin( sint)) dt\\
f'( x) =1+sin( sin( sin( x)) *cosx\\
( from\ Leibnitz\ formula)\\
Let\ f^{-1}( 0) =y\\
then\ f( y) =0,\ so\ y=0
\end{gather*}
Im sure you can take it from here. Just find f'(0) and then you are done.